# How to find checksum matches between two lists (but not within the two lists)?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I want to find duplicates between two folders based on  lists with checksums.

A solution with some shell script (some *bash*, *awk* or similar) would be best.

Assume that for the two folders I have already generated two lists

```
[FolderA.txt]
file1 abc1
file2 abc1
file3 def5
```

and

```
[FolderB.txt]
file4 abc1
file5 mno2
file6 def5
```

Now I want to find out, that

- file1 matches file4 (same checksum abc1)
- file2 matches file4 (same checksum abc1)
- file3 matches file6 (same checksum def5)

However, I only want matches between folders, not within one folder. Hence, I do NOT want a match between file1 and file2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
join -j2 <(sort -k2 FolderA.txt) <(sort -k2 FolderB.txt)
```

Output:

```
abc1 file1 file4
abc1 file2 file4
def5 file3 file6
```

If you want only column 2 and 3, add `| cut -d " " -f 2-`

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. As I learned now, to show only the file names, one can also use the parameter `-o 1.1,2.1` with `join`.

Comment: Option `-o` is very nice.